# NONDETERMINISTIC function uses DETERMINISTIC function

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am not sure about DETERMINISTIC / NONDETERMINISTIC definition for below function. function1 function is NOT DETERMINISTIC but includes DETERMINISTIC function (function2). Should I change it as DETERMINISTIC because of having DETERMINISTIC function inside?

```
CREATE FUNCTION function1 (a varchar(12), bDate timestamp, cDate timestamp, insertCache bool, forceNotToUseCache bool, e INT(10), f INT(10))

**RETURNS DOUBLE
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA**

BEGIN

DECLARE v_value double default null;

    IF (condition)
        THEN
            do stuff
        ELSE
            SELECT function2(a, bDate, cDate, insertCache, forceNotToUseCache) into v_value;
            RETURN(v_value);
    END IF;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3):

From the definition:

> Deterministic functions always return the same result any time they are called with a specific set of input values and given the same state of the database. Nondeterministic functions may return different results each time they are called with a specific set of input values even if the database state that they access remains the same.

In your case, if you do not directly return the deterministic result of `fuction2`, but instead use something non deterministic in your `condition` e.g. something depending on the current date, then **`function1` remains non deterministic**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure about DETERMINISTIC / NONDETERMINISTIC definition

When **ALL** actions/calls are deterministic - the function is deterministic.

When **AT LEAST ONE** action/call is not deterministic - the whole function is not deterministic.

---

For example, to define a function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION fn () 
RETURNS INT 
BEGIN 
    SET @tmp:=NOW(); -- non-deterministic call !
    RETURN 1; 
END
```

as deterministic is ideological error despite the fact that its result is deterministic.

Comment: This function is still deterministic because the observable effects are deterministic.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Distinguish between "the function is deterministic" and "the function is declared as deterministic", please.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the function you show can be declared deterministic.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You can, of course. I'll do it never personally, by the reason explained above.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Synthetic scenario. A creates huge function with small nondeterministic block and defines function as nondeterministic. Then the method slightly changes temporarily, and B has commented this block. С searches the way for optimization and redefines the function as deterministic. Change expires, and D uncomments this block but what he missed was that the function was redefined as deterministic. Everyone is happy... :)